# SSE4 and SSE2 regarding integer and float performance - which is faster?

Tags: c++, cpu, sse, simd

While you *usually* get better integer arithmetic performance than floating point performance on CPUs, could someone clarify what the case is with the SIMD versions.For instance:

```
 __m128i _mm_mul_epi32(__m128i a, __m128i b);
//(multiplies 2 integer vectors)
```

versus:

```
__m128 _mm_mul_ps(__m128 a , __m128 b );
//(multiplies 2 float vectors)
```

Which yields higher performance?(assuming the machine has SSE4 capabilities).I'm saying this, because I coded my own little math library based on SSE2 instructions and I don't know if I should have went right on with using __m128i.

Comment: Measure it and find out.

Comment: It depends on the specific CPU - see the ever-useful [Agner Fog docs](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) for details of throughput and latency for these instructions on various different CPUs.

Comment: They are bot executed in a single clock. Check the white paper from Intel

Comment: On Haswell it can do two `_mm256_mul_ps` but only one `_mm256_mul_epi32` per clock cycle so on Haswell the float option is clearly going to be faster.

Comment: I thought on x86 CPUs integer multiplication/division is more expensive than floating-point...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show the first place I go to answer these types of questions: the [Intel Intrinsic Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) online. You provide the intrinsic and it tells you what it does and provides the latency and throughput for Nehalem through Haswell (and soon Broadwell) processors. Here are the results:

_mm_mul_ps

```
                Latency    Reciprocal throughput
Haswell         5          0.5
Ivy Bridge      5          1
Sandy Bridge    5          1
Westmere        4          1
Nehalem         4          1
```

_mm_mul_epi32

```
                Latency    Reciprocal throughput
Haswell         5          1
Ivy Bridge      3          1
Sandy Bridge    3          1
Westmere        3          1
Nehalem         3          1
```

Lower latency and reciprocal throughput are better. From these tables we can conclude that

- except for Haswell the latency for `_mm_mul_epi32` is less than for `_mm_mul_ps`,
- on Haswell the latency is the same,
- except for Haswell the throughput is the same,
- on Haswell the throughput for `_mm_mul_ps` is twice that of `_mm_mul_epi32`.

The throughput on Haswell is the only major surprise.

If you want the results for pre-Nehalem processors and/or for AMD processors then see Agner Fog's [Instruction tables manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) or run his [tests programs](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp) which he used to measure the latency and throughput.

Comment: When Agner's numbers differ from Intel's numbers, I tend to trust Agner's numbers. Since they are based on actual benchmarks and not some theoretical limit the hardware can do under optimal circumstances. I've also found some errors in Intel's numbers. (probably someone made a mistake while copying numbers from some internal table into that guide)

Comment: @Mysticial, I just realized there is a subtle issue here. `_mm_mul_epi32` does not multiple four numbers. It multiplies the lower 32-bits of two 64-bit numbers and returns two 64-bit numbers. So its effective throughput is already half of `_mm_mul_ps`. Maybe it makes more sense to compare to `_mm_mullo_epi32` which does multiply four and return four.

Comment: Yeah. Note that `_mm_mullo_epi32` is 2 uops on Nehalem and Westmere. I guess the vector unit doesn't have four 32x32 multipliers. So it's probably feeding it into the double-precision multiplier twice.

Comment: @Mysticial, yeah, and the latency on Nehalem and Westerere is also twice (which makes sense if it's done twice). And on Haswell the latency is 10! Why is the latency worse in general on Haswell?

Comment: Agner says it's throughput 2 on Haswell going into port 0. So it looks like it's being fed twice into the 5-cycle multiplier which is used for both FP-mul and FP-FMA. It looks like all integer multiply vector instructions go to port 0 with the 5-cycle latency.

Comment: Agner lists the integer multiply latencies as 5 cycles on Sandy/Ivy. So it looks like the only thing they did on Haswell was take out the "dense" 32-bit multiply and double-cycle the `pmulld` instruction through the double-precision multiplier. After all, it is the only instruction that needs it. So I guess they wanted that extra area for something else. :)